# How to convert varchar(10) column to timestamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, timestamp, laravel-5

I have an old Database table with varchar(10) column  with timestamp data.

Now i am using laravel web app on that Database.

I need to convert varchar(10)  column to timestamp with data.

Previously i have change the column Type using phpmyadmin (on a backup copy) but all the data were change to 0000000000.

How can i do this Properly without any data lost.

```
timestamp   varchar(10)     utf8_general_ci         No  None
```

`sampel data:(in varchar)
1246251403
1246251404
1248771150`

Comment: what is the format of timestamp data stored in varchar column?

Comment: Can you give an example of timestamp data?

Comment: you can't simply change the `dataType` of that column and make things work. First you need to create a new `column` with `timestapm` data type. then perform a update query to set `timestamp` value converting the string value you have using proper functions based on the format.

Comment: sample data added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your string to a *timestamp* using `from_unixtime()`. It will run fine on a `VARCHAR` column.

Example :

```
create table mytable (oldts varchar(10), newts timestamp NULL);

insert into mytable (oldts,newts) values ('1246251403', NULL);
insert into mytable (oldts,newts) values ('1246251404', NULL);
insert into mytable (oldts,newts) values ('1246251404', NULL);

update mytable SET newts = from_unixtime(oldts);

select oldts, newts from mytable;
```

Results :

```
|      oldts |                newts |
|------------|----------------------|
| 1246251403 | 2009-06-29T04:56:43Z |
| 1246251404 | 2009-06-29T04:56:44Z |
| 1246251404 | 2009-06-29T04:56:44Z |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7234/1)